# Get the 1 top result for multiple ID's using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running an elastic search where I need to find the most recent data based on an UNIQUE_ID.

I usually do it like below.

```
## There are multiple entries for each UNIQUE_ID and each has an unique timestamp field
{
    "size": 1,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "ID": {"query": "<UNIQUE_ID>"}
                    }
                }
                ]
            }
        },
        "sort": [
        {
            "@timestamp": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
        ]
}
```

I now have an issue with scale, where I have say a 1000 UNIQUE_ID's.
I do not want to run the above query 1000 times, instead is there a way to provide a list of UNIQUE_ID's so that I can get 1 result  for each of UNIQUE_ID in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) to match multiple ID, then combine your condition with [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), it works like `group by` in sql to group by ID

Comment: Thank you. This works.

For a data set of 10, the individual queries take less time than a single query with aggregation buckets. Is this a elastic search thing or its probably the way I structured my query?